# How to pass an alias from a database query into a loop for output in Wordpress

Tags: php, sql, wordpress

I am querying the database in Wordpress to retrieve `comment_content` in the `wp_comments` table as well as the `meta_value` of 2 `meta_key`s in the `wp_commentmeta` table. My aim is to take every comment in the database and output it within a list, with each list item displaying the comment, as well as my 2 `commentmeta` items (name and country).

I am using an alias for each meta_key as so:

```
$querystr = " SELECT * FROM $wpdb->comments, $wpdb->commentmeta AS commentmeta1, $wpdb->commentmeta AS commentmeta2 
WHERE $wpdb->comments.comment_ID = commentmeta1.comment_id 
AND $wpdb->comments.comment_ID = commentmeta2.comment_id 
AND commentmeta1.meta_key = 'comment_name' 
AND commentmeta2.meta_key = 'comment_country' ORDER BY $wpdb->comments.comment_date DESC";
$comment_info =  $wpdb->get_results($querystr, OBJECT);
```

I then run run my loop to display my results:

```
    echo '<ul>';
    // display the results
    foreach($comment_info as $info) { 
    echo '<li class="commentBox"><p>' . $info->comment_content . '</p>
    <h6>' . $info->meta_value['commentmeta1'] . ', ' . $info->meta_value['commentmeta2'] . '</h6></li>'; 
    }
    echo '</ul>';
```

What I need to do is pass the alias I defined for each `meta_key` into my loop so I can display it's respective `meta_value`. I tried using `$info->comment_content` and `$info->meta_value['commentmeta2']` but it doesn't work. Using `$info->meta_value` only displays commentmeta2. Can anybody help?

Comment: Part of your problem is that the *fields* are not being aliased, only the *tables*.  This means that the final result set has fields from commentmeta1 and commentmeta2 with the exact same *(ambiguous)* names.  Try using something like `SELECT commentmeta1.meta_value AS comment_name, commentmeta2.meta_value AS comment_country` to  give your result set's fields explicit aliases.

Comment: MatBailie thank you very much for replying. Your advice worked perfectly! I am posting the final code below as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to *MatBailie's* suggestion, the final working code is as follows:

```
$querystr = " SELECT comment_content, commentmeta1.meta_value AS comment_name, commentmeta2.meta_value AS comment_country 
FROM $wpdb->comments, $wpdb->commentmeta AS commentmeta1, $wpdb->commentmeta AS commentmeta2 
WHERE $wpdb->comments.comment_ID = commentmeta1.comment_id 
AND $wpdb->comments.comment_ID = commentmeta2.comment_id 
AND commentmeta1.meta_key = 'comment_name' 
AND commentmeta2.meta_key = 'comment_country' ORDER BY $wpdb->comments.comment_date DESC";

$comment_info =  $wpdb->get_results($querystr, OBJECT);

echo '<ul>';
// display the results
foreach($comment_info as $info) { 
echo '<li class="commentBox"><p>' . $info->comment_content . '</p>
<h6>' . $info->comment_name . ', ' . $info->comment_country . '</h6></li>'; 
}

echo '</ul>';
```